# yii generate automatic form without model

Tags: php, yii

I'm using Yii and I'm trying to do a automatic form generator, I have an array for a fields depend the case, but I don't know how don't use the model with `CActiveForm` because when I create an input like this (code below), I receive the message

```
"Property "cusform.hJd8tiZ7cn" is not defined."
```

`hJd8tiZ7cn` is the id of my custom field obviously this is not an attribute for my model, thanks for your help.

```
<?php
//view
foreach($arrfields as $af){
?>
    <div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,$af['xlabel']); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,$af['xobjectId'],array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>128)); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,$af['xobjectId']); ?>
    </div>

<?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`CHtml`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml) helper classes.

[`CActiveForm`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveForm) calls `CHtml` to generate the form, Most methods of CActiveForm are wrappers of the corresponding 'active' methods in CHtml.

`CActiveForm` and the active CHtml classes are meant only for ActiveRecord form generation, i.e. forms based on active-records. Since you do not know the field names and they are not linked to a DB field in advance you do something simply like this

```
<?php
//view
foreach($arrfields as $af):
    <div class="row">
        <?php echo CHtml::label($af['xlabel'],$af['xobjectId'] ); ?>
        <?php echo CHtml::textField($af['xobjectId'],"",array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>128)); ?>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

This will genertate static fields for you, but it will not give you all the features of using activeRecord forms such as validation and errors, if you want errors you will have to build your own CForm models, with rules and actions etc, see how to use [form builder](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/form.builder) without depending on active record objects